# transforming SOAP response into NSString

Tags: objective-c, web-services, soap, wsdl

```
NSString *GetExRequest=[NSString stringWithFormat:
                        @"<?xmlversion=\"1.0\"encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                        "<soap:Envelopexmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance\"xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                        "<soap:Body>\n"
                        "<GetEXRatexmlns=\"Web Services\">\n"
                        "<AGENT_CODE>xyzzyx</AGENT_CODE>\n"
                        "<USER_ID>12345689</USER_ID>\n"
                        "<PASSWORD>dkasdja</PASSWORD>\n"
                        "<AGENT_SESSION_ID>xyz1234</AGENT_SESSION_ID>\n"
                        "<TRANSFERAMOUNT>1000</TRANSFERAMOUNT>\n"
                        "<PAYMENTMODE>c</PAYMENTMODE>\n"
                        "<CALC_BY>p</CALC_BY>\n"
                        "<PAYOUT_AGENT_ID>20100008</PAYOUT_AGENT_ID>\n"
                        "<PAYOUT_COUNTRY>Bangladesh</PAYOUT_COUNTRY>\n"
                        "</GetEXRate>\n"
                        "</soap:Body>\n"
                        "</soap:Envelope>\n"];
NSLog(@"%@",GetExRequest);
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://www.prabhuusa.com/SendWsv2/txnservice.asmx?wsdl"];
NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
NSString *msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [GetExRequest length]];
[theRequest addValue:@"www.prabhuusa.com" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Host"];
[theRequest addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[theRequest addValue: @"WebServices/GetEXRate" forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
[theRequest addValue: msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[theRequest setHTTPBody: [GetExRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSURLConnection *theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:theRequest delegate:self];

    if( theConnection )
{
    webData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"theConnection is NULL");
}
```

I am trying to consume this WSDL definition by sending this SOAP request. I wanted to store the response onto a string and the parse it.

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    NSLog(@"DONE. Received Bytes: %d", [_webData length]);
    NSString *theXML = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes: [_webData mutableBytes] length:[_webData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"WEBDATA::: %@",theXML);
}
```

But the Response string is blank. I checked this webservice with the SOAP request I sent using SOAP Client and received a XML response.. but i could not get a response in objective C. Please find me a solution

I have this in my didRecieveResponse and didRecieveData methods

```
-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{

    [_webData setLength: 0];
}

-(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  
{ 
[_webData appendData:data];
}
```

Comment: Do you ever initialize `_webData` as `[NSMutableData data]` (for examine in `didReceiveResponse`)? Do you append data to it in `didReceiveData`? In `connectionDidFinishLoading`, is `_webData` a `NSMutableData` with length of zero, or is it `nil`? (BTW, I generally use `initWithData` rather than `initWithBytes`, as it seems more intuitive, but that's not the source of your issue.)

Comment: Sorry, I have added my 'didRecieveResponse' and 'diRecieveData' codes here as well. If I mess up the SOAP ACTION header, I get a fault response in XML format, so I guess the recieving end is correct, Something i might be doing wrong while sending the request?

Comment: @YugeshShresta You're still not showing where you instantiate `webData` (and if you're getting `nil` for a response, that's a typical problem). But if you're getting a response, and its reporting an error, then it might be in your request. For example, I notice you have an open tag `<GetEXRatexmlns="Web Services">` and I assume that should have been `<GetEXRate xmlns="Web Services">`. But I really don't know if there might be other issues (the nature of the request can vary and I don't know what your service is looking for).

Comment: Also `<soap:Envelopexmlns:xsi="...">` looks suspicious. Perhaps `<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="...">`. And `<?xmlversion="1.0"encoding="utf-8"?>` should probably be `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`. Looks like you've removed a lot of spaces.

Comment: Also, shouldn't the agent code be `xyzzy`? (Just kidding: Just revealing my [misspent childhood](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xyzzy).)

Comment: I have corrected the spaces, and added the instatiation code. I still get empty response. :(

Comment: The code sample above is still missing the spaces, but I assume you've actually fixed it in your app. Perhaps you can update the question showing the corrected request code ...

Comment: Also, you're instantiating `webData`, but reading `_webData`. Those are two different instance variables. And I'd instantiate it in `didReceiveResponse` or before you create the connection. What you've got probably works, but it's a little dangerous to start the connection and _then_ only instantiate the `NSMutableData` after you return. Probably works, but safer to do before or in `didReceiveResponse`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two possible issues that leap out at me:

1. You never show the instantiation of the `webData` property. Check to make sure it is not `nil`.
2. Your request appears to be missing some spaces. Shouldn't it be as follows?

   ```
   NSString *GetExRequest= @"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>\n"
                           "<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchemainstance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">\n"
                           "<soap:Body>\n"
                           "<GetEXRate xmlns=\"Web Services\">\n"
                           "<AGENT_CODE>xyzzyx</AGENT_CODE>\n"
                           "<USER_ID>12345689</USER_ID>\n"
                           "<PASSWORD>dkasdja</PASSWORD>\n"
                           "<AGENT_SESSION_ID>xyz1234</AGENT_SESSION_ID>\n"
                           "<TRANSFERAMOUNT>1000</TRANSFERAMOUNT>\n"
                           "<PAYMENTMODE>c</PAYMENTMODE>\n"
                           "<CALC_BY>p</CALC_BY>\n"
                           "<PAYOUT_AGENT_ID>20100008</PAYOUT_AGENT_ID>\n"
                           "<PAYOUT_COUNTRY>Bangladesh</PAYOUT_COUNTRY>\n"
                           "</GetEXRate>\n"
                           "</soap:Body>\n"
                           "</soap:Envelope>\n";
   ```

Comment: I changed the spaces and all and tried, still gave me an empty response. I got hopeless and replaced with your change in my code and it worked.. Thank you very very much.!! I must have missed one more space somewhere that I still don't know :P   Thank you!! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think you can not reveal WSDL end point without any prior Notice to concern people, I request you to remove WSDL link you have mentioned on above question.